# Найти сумму элементов, стоящих на пересечениях нечетных строк и нечетных столбцов

Tags: c++

```
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
setlocale(0,"");
const int n=4, m=7;
int A[m][n], i, j;
cout<<"Л/р №7  вариант 10"<<endl;
cout<<"--------------------------------------------"<<endl;
cout<<"Введите матрицу A размером "<<n<<" на "<<m<<endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

Пересечение нечетных строк и нечетных столбцов, это во:

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6
0 _ _ _ _ _ _ _
1 _ √ _ √ _ √ _
2 _ _ _ _ _ _ _
3 _ √ _ √ _ √ _
```

Нужно два вложенных цикла, начиная с 1, увеличивать счетчики на 2:

```
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 1; i < m; i += 2)
{
    for (int j = 1; j < n; j += 2)
    {
        sum += A[i][j];
    }
}

cout << sum;
```

А можно посчитать прямо во время заполнения:

```
const int m = 7, n = 4;
int A[m][n], sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        cout << "Input A[" << i << "][" << j << "]: ";
        cin >> A[i][j];

        if (i % 2 == 1 && j % 2 == 1) sum += A[i][j];
    }
}

cout << sum;
```

Comment: можно `if(1 & i & j)`

Comment: а лучше вообще без условия   (int i = 1; i < m; i += 2)